# Adjacency Matrix of a Graph Length of Paths Proof

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, proof-writing

Let A be an adjacency matrix of a graph $G$. Prove that the $(i, j)^{th}$ entry of $A^2$ is the number of paths of length $2$ between vertex $i$ and vertex $j$.

*I know the adjacency matrix will be a square matrix.

I would appreciate any help explaining this problem and advice of where to begin this proof.

Comment: Hint: work a small example and pay attention to the terms in the sum that calculates the $i,j$ entry.

Comment: In fact the number of paths of length $n$ is $A^n_{i,j}$.

Comment: Of walks, sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of paths of length $2$ from $u$ to $v$ is equal to the sum over $w\in V$ of all the ways to get from $u$ to $w$ multiplied by all the ways to get from $w$ to $v$, in one step. So it is the sum over $w\in G$ of  $A_{u,w}A_{w,v}$. This is exactly $A^2_{uv}$.

Answer (score 0):

Element $A_{ij}$ is $1$ if there is a path between $i$ and $j$ and $0$ if there is not.

Likewise, element $(A^2)_{ij}$ is $1$ if there is a $2$-step path between $i$ and $j$ and $0$ if there is not.

In general, element $(A^k)_{ij}$ is $1$ if there is a $k$-step path between $i$ and $j$ and $0$ if there is not.

Play with some simples graphs and you will see this clarly.